# Sidekiq fails after start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, foreman

After

```
    foreman start
```

I`m getting

```
    11:57:26 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 18203
    11:57:28 sidekiq.1 | exited with code 0
    11:57:28 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

And in logs:

```
    # Logfile created on 2017-04-21 12:14:44 -0400 by logger.rb/56438
```

Proc

```
 sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -d -l sidekiq.log
```

When I run Proc command manually everything seems fine. Where may I be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't daemonize or redirect logs.  Change Procfile to:

```
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
```